# How $q works in angularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, q

I like to know how $q works in angular , lets say i a have few lines of code to execute.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('HelloCtrl', function ($q, $scope) {

    $scope.Title = "Promise Demo";

    function asyncGreetings(name) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        setTimeout(function() {

            deferred.notify('About to greet ' + name + '.');
            if (name == "binson") {
                deferred.resolve("Hello " + name);
            } else {
                deferred.reject("Greeting not allowed ");
            }

        }, 5000);

        return deferred.promise;
    };


    $scope.CurrentName = "";
    var promise = asyncGreetings('binson');

    promise.then(function(greeting) {
        $scope.CurrentName='Success: ' + greeting;
    }, function(reason) {
        $scope.CurrentName ='Failed: ' + reason;
    }, function (update) {

        $scope.Progress = 'Got notification: ' + update;
    });


 });
```

This is sample code, here a mock async  function asyncGreetings() and will execute after 5 seconds, what i want to show a progress ( a simple alert box or any thing ) until the promises collected to the caller, i think i configured the  caller function properly with 3 parameters (success,fails,progress). but the progress handler is not working.. what is the problem here, and how i can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The progress handler doesn't update automatically.

You must provide the updates by using `deferred.notify('message')` in a similar manner to resolve/reject.

[see plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gHNhwvNZvgtjtKsdacJn?p=preview)

When dealing with timeouts and intervals it is best practice to use the angular provided $timeout and $interval services that wrap the native javascript functions. Just be sure to include them in your providers.

Instead of using `clearTimeout(timeout_instance)` and `clearInterval(interval_instance)` use `$timeout.cancel(timeout_instance)` or `$interval.cancel(interval_instance)`

Comment: OP is using `deferred.notify`

Answer (score 1):

You have the notification inside the same 5 second timeout so it will only trigger at the end of the 5 seconds

If you set the notification in a different interval loop your progress callback works fine

```
   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          deferred.notify('Notification #' + (i + 1));
        }, i * 1000);
      })(i);
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      if (name == "binson") {
        deferred.resolve("Hello " + name);
      } else {
        deferred.reject("Greeting not allowed ");
      }

    }, 5000);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/wdb49UeyNyESxCOiiS5p?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

All the above solutions are very good to clear my doubts about q, and here i have a pretty good solution with all angular utilities . i changed my async function  , now it calling defer.notify()  using $interval

```
function asyncGreetings(name) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var progress = 0;

        var interval = $interval(function() {

            if (progress >= 100) {
                $interval.cancel(interval);
            }
            progress += 10;

            deferred.notify(progress);
        },1000);
        $timeout(function() {

          //  deferred.notify('About to greet ' + name + '.');
            if (name == "binson") {
                deferred.resolve("Hello " + name);
            } else {
                deferred.reject("Greeting not allowed ");
            }

        }, 10000);

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

and i added one parameters called $interval,$timeout in my controller (dependency injected)

```
app.controller('HelloCtrl', function ($q, $scope, $interval,$timeout) {///}
```